# Laravel eloquent get extra column value as response

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table named `user`

```
id | country | people | women
1  | USA     |   8    | 3
2  | BD      |   9    | 5
```

In laravel 5.4 i can get all table data using

```
$user = User::all();
```

This returns the user table with those column. but i want to get an extra column value `man = people-women` as output. 
How can i get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the User model add the following lines:

```
protected $appends = ['man'];

    public function getManAttribute()
    {
        return $this->people  - $this->women;
    }
```

I have not tested this solution, but in theory it should work

Source in the bottom of the page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

Please let me know if It worked. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new attribute in your model that is a `getter`:

```
public function getMenAttribute()
{
    return $this->people - $this->women;
}
```

Then when looping over the `$users`:

```
$users->each(function($user){
    // use $user->men;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new attribute, here an example

```
\App\Models\Sede::with(
                [
                    'area_trabajos' => function($query) {
                        $query->select('*',DB::raw('"false" as borrado'));
                    },
                    'empresa',
                    'puestos'
                ])->addSelect('*',DB::raw('id*id as newColum'))->get()->toJson()
```

return

```
[{"id":4,"created_at":"2018-06-01 04:56:57","updated_at":"2018-06-01 05:46:50","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Empresa_id":61,"numero_trabajadores":8,"nombre_sede":"ii","newColum":16,"area_trabajos":[{"id":1,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:55:19","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:55:19","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":2,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:55:19","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:55:19","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":3,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:55:19","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:55:19","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":4,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:14","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:14","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":5,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:14","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:14","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":6,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:14","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:14","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":7,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:49","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:49","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":8,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:49","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:49","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":9,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:49","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:56:49","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":10,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:58:31","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:58:31","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":11,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:58:31","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:58:31","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":12,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:59:32","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:59:32","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":13,"created_at":"2018-06-01 07:59:32","updated_at":"2018-06-01 07:59:32","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":14,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:00:17","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:00:17","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":15,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:00:17","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:00:17","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":16,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:04","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:04","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":17,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:04","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:04","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":18,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:27","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:27","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":19,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:27","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:27","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":20,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:52","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:52","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":21,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:52","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:02:52","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":22,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:03:22","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:03:22","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"},{"id":23,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:03:22","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:03:22","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":4,"nombre":"Nueva area","borrado":"false"}],"empresa":{"id":61,"created_at":"2018-05-31 08:07:29","updated_at":"2018-06-01 05:11:24","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"nombre":"Jose","ruc":"898987"},"puestos":[]},{"id":5,"created_at":"2018-06-01 04:59:59","updated_at":"2018-06-01 04:59:59","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Empresa_id":63,"numero_trabajadores":9,"nombre_sede":"iii","newColum":25,"area_trabajos":[{"id":24,"created_at":"2018-06-01 08:16:10","updated_at":"2018-06-01 08:16:10","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Sede_id":5,"nombre":"kkk","borrado":"false"}],"empresa":{"id":63,"created_at":"2018-06-01 02:00:48","updated_at":"2018-06-01 02:00:48","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"nombre":"Javier","ruc":"7777"},"puestos":[]},{"id":6,"created_at":"2018-06-01 05:00:39","updated_at":"2018-06-01 05:00:39","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Empresa_id":63,"numero_trabajadores":89,"nombre_sede":"iii","newColum":36,"area_trabajos":[],"empresa":{"id":63,"created_at":"2018-06-01 02:00:48","updated_at":"2018-06-01 02:00:48","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"nombre":"Javier","ruc":"7777"},"puestos":[]},{"id":7,"created_at":"2018-06-01 05:01:50","updated_at":"2018-06-01 05:01:50","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Empresa_id":63,"numero_trabajadores":9,"nombre_sede":"ppp","newColum":49,"area_trabajos":[],"empresa":{"id":63,"created_at":"2018-06-01 02:00:48","updated_at":"2018-06-01 02:00:48","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"nombre":"Javier","ruc":"7777"},"puestos":[]},{"id":8,"created_at":"2018-06-01 05:02:24","updated_at":"2018-06-01 05:02:24","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"Empresa_id":63,"numero_trabajadores":78,"nombre_sede":"oioioioioio","newColum":64,"area_trabajos":[],"empresa":{"id":63,"created_at":"2018-06-01 02:00:48","updated_at":"2018-06-01 02:00:48","deleted_at":null,"auditoria_estado":null,"auditoria_user":null,"nombre":"Javier","ruc":"7777"},"puestos":[]}]
```